# How can I change my Sony Vaio Windows 7 from japanese to english language?

Tags: windows-7

I'm using Sony Vaio windows 7 professional. My concern is also it is not ulitimate or enterprise, therefore maybe it has a different method.

Comment: Do you want the keyboard language or the whole Windows 7 OS to change?